# AngularJS add array to json form object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

This is an AngularJS 1.4.7 question.

I got a form that stores all its data in an object in the $scope of the controller

```
$scope.my_form={};
```

I push data from a type ahead field to another array

```
$scope.products=[];
```

I need to merge my_form and products to get the following result

```
{
 "CustomerCode" : "C232",
 "CustomerName" : "Big Buyer",
 "Products" : ["P190","P221","P98"]
}
```

So far i got both arrays but i can not

A. Concat the json object and the array
B. Add the word Products before the array as well

I think its a piece of cake but well i am new

Thanks guys!

Comment: Where is CustomerName and CustomerCode located? also on the scope?

Comment: Yes CustomerCode and CustomerName are within the same scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
  $scope.my_form.products = $scope.products;
```

If you don't want the reference just clone the object

// Shallow copy

```
   $scope.my_form.products = jQuery.extend({}, $scope.products);
```

// Deep copy

```
   $scope.my_form.products = jQuery.extend(true, {}, $scope.products);
```

Comment: The result of the jQuery was {"CustomerCode" : "C232", "CustomerName" :"Big Buyer", "Products": {"0":"P1001"} } which did not satisfy the requirements. This ( $scope.my_form.products = $scope.products;) did the job

Comment: your $scope.products is not a array object you need to convert it to array

Comment: btw the jQuery.extend is not applicable to array is just a one more way to copy object

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro just studied that now there is an angular.extend as well.

Answer (score 0):

Only add,

```
$scope.my_form.Products = $scope.products
```